# MyIsam fulltext search against multiple %term%

Tags: mysql, sql, search, full-text-search, myisam

I have a field called filepath that I'm trying to search. Here is an example path:

```
/mnt/qfs-X/Asset_Management/XG_Marketing_/Episodic-SG_1001_1233.jpg
```

I would like to be able to search the following and get a match:

```
search = "qf episodic sg_1001 JPG"
```

How would I do this with a fulltext search in mysql/myisam? What I have now is:

```
SELECT * FROM x_files2 WHERE MATCH(path)
AGAINST('qf episodic sg_1001 JPG' in boolean mode)
```

But it is returning way too many results (seems like it's returning if any terms are found instead of only those where all are found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `+` in front of each 'word':

```
AGAINST('+qf* +episodic +sg_1001* +JPG' in boolean mode)
```

Do you have the min-word-length set to 2?  If not, there could be other troubles.

The `+` avoids "too many".

Consider switching to InnoDB, now that it has `FULLTEXT`.

You may have to abandon use of FULLTEXT and switch to `LIKE`:

```
WHERE path LIKE '%qf%episodic%sg_1001%JPG%'
```

If performance is an issue, consider something like

```
WHERE MATCH(path) AGAINST('...' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  -- using some of the words
  AND path LIKE '...'   -- as above
```

The `MATCH` will run first, whittling down the number of possible rows considerably, then the `LIKE` takes care of details.

Note that middles of words cannot be used in `AGAINST`.  Those could be left out, relying on `LIKE` to take care of them.

Comment: there are no "words" though, it's just a file path. Even doing `+qf` doesn't work unless I put a wildcard there -- `+qf*`.

Comment: @David542 - I added `*` and some other thoughts.

Comment: thanks for this detailed answer. I ended up going another route as it didn't seem like the fulltext helped too much with my needs here